# NHibernate: Populate new entities relative properties with foreign key ID

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have structured my NHibernate models to hide the foreign key IDs as seems to be best practice, so instead of having both the relationship and the key modeled like this:

```
public class CompanyOffice
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I simply have:

```
public class CompanyOffice
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And let NHibernate take car of the rest.  I like this, but I have a few tables with multiple foreign keys that need setting and when I create a new entity, in an MVC action, I'm having to do this:

```
public ActionResult CreateNewThing(int stuffId, int whatId, int blahId)
{
    var stuff = _service.GetStuffById(stuffId);
    var what = _service.GetWhatById(whatId);
    var blah = _service.GetBlahById(blahId);

    var thing = new Thing { Stuff = stuff, What = what, Blah = blah };
}
```

Which means three trips to the database to get the entities, when I don't really need them as I already have the IDs and could have just done:

```
var thing = new Thing { StuffId = stuffId, WhatId = whatId, BlahId = blahId };
```

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do without hitting the database for the entities?
Should I just bite the bullet and map the foreign keys as well as the relationships?
Or am I being to concerned about the database trips and should I just crack on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to avoid mapping the FK Id, to avoid 3 addtional trips do this:-

```
var thing = new Thing {
  Stuff = session.Load<Stuff>(20),
  What = session.Load<What>(21),
  Blah = session.Load<Blah>(2234),
}
```

`session.Load` is slightly different to `session.Get`

Also it is worth noting that `Thing.Stuff.Id` also does not hit the database.

This is a [great post](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/), I quote:-

> In session.load(), Hibernate will not hit the database (no select
>   statement in output) to retrieve the Stock object, it will return a
>   Stock proxy object – a fake object with given identify value. In this
>   scenario, a proxy object is enough for to save a stock transaction
>   record.

Comment: Okay, that definitely answers my question, but I'm now struggling to fit that into my design.  My controllers use service classes within my business layer, which use repositories in my data layer.  Should I add a Load() method to my repositories and then have a CreateThing(stuffId, whatId, blahId) method in my service?

Comment: Sometimes you can abstract away the goodness of NH in a repository layer, In this case I would expose the session so you can utilize all the goodness that NH brings. I have a generic `service` layer that has something like:-       public ISession Db
      {
         get
         {
            return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
         }
      } this means I can then do this in my controller Db.Load<Blah>(1) and even hit the DB using Db.Query<Blah>.Where(w=>w.Name == 'Richard')

Comment: Do you know if this has been enhanced at all since 2013? This is a very common usecase and a weird solution to get around it. I would assume Fluent Nhibernate would have something in place for this.